# Crash gutter icon in Android Studio not showing?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 version and the App Quality Insights are a really great addition to the tool. I can see the list of crashes in that windows, but it doesn't highlight the codebase with that gutter icon for a crash next to the lines of code.

Anyone else with the same problem?